# How to Query parquet data from Amazon Athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, parquet, amazon-athena

Athena creates a temporary table using fields in S3 table. I have done this using JSON data. Could you help me on how to create table using parquet data?

I have tried following:

1. Converted sample JSON data to parquet data.
2. Uploaded parquet data to S3.
3. Created temporary table using columns of JSON data.

By doing this I am able to a execute query but the result is empty.

Is this approach right or is there any other approach to be followed on parquet data?

Sample json data:

```
{"_id":"0899f824e118d390f57bc2f279bd38fe","_rev":"1-81cc25723e02f50cb6fef7ce0b0f4f38","deviceId":"BELT001","timestamp":"2016-12-21T13:04:10:066Z","orgid":"fedex","locationId":"LID001","UserId":"UID001","SuperviceId":"SID001"},
{"_id":"0899f824e118d390f57bc2f279bd38fe","_rev":"1-81cc25723e02f50cb6fef7ce0b0f4f38","deviceId":"BELT001","timestamp":"2016-12-21T13:04:10:066Z","orgid":"fedex","locationId":"LID001","UserId":"UID001","SuperviceId":"SID001"}
```

Comment: Would you please share your Athena table definition?  What tool did you use to generate Parquet files?

Comment: If you perform a `SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 5`, does it return any data? If not, then your table definition is not valid.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If your data has been successfully stored in Parquet format, you would then create a table definition that references those files.

Here is an example statement that uses Parquet files:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS elb_logs_pq (
  request_timestamp string,
  elb_name string,
  request_ip string,
  request_port int,
  ...
  ssl_protocol string )
PARTITIONED BY(year int, month int, day int) 
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://athena-examples/elb/parquet/'
tblproperties ("parquet.compress"="SNAPPY");
```

This example was taken from the AWS blog post [Analyzing Data in S3 using Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/) that does an excellent job of explaining the benefits of using compressed and partitioned data in Amazon Athena.

Comment: Can you exclude partitions? For example only include day 1, 3, 5 and exclude all other days.

Comment: I assume the table data is updated when the data on s3 changes? That means A) when there is a deletion rule on s3 the data is deleted at the table B) when new days are added on S3 then the data is added to the table

Answer (score 2):

If your table definition is valid but not getting any rows, try this

-- The MSCK REPAIR TABLE command will load all partitions into the table. 
-- This command can take a while to run depending on the number of partitions to be loaded.

MSCK REPAIR TABLE {tablename}

Answer (score 1):

steps:
1. create your my_table_json
2. insert data into my_table_json (verify existence of the created json files in the table 'LOCATION')
3. **create my_table_parquet: same create statement as my_table_json except you need to add 'STORED AS PARQUET' clause.**
4. **run:** `INSERT INTO my_table_parquet SELECT * FROM my_table_json`